# How to sort a list by the amount of clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following list in html

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  font-size: 1vw;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}

#bbb {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/BBB.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#plus {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/50PLUS.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position-y: 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#bvnl {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/BVNL.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#cda {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/Cda.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#christenunie {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/ChristenUnie.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#d66 {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/D66.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#denk {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/Denk.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#fvd {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/FVD.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ja21 {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/JA21.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#nsc {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/nsc.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#pvda {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/PVDAGROENLINKS.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#pvdd {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/PVDD.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#pvv {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/PVV.jpeg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#sgp {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/SGP.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#sp {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/SP.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#vvd {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/VVD.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#volt {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/Volt.png);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#vvd {
  background-image: url(Assets/PartijAfbeeldingen/VVD.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul id="Partijensort" class="grid-container">
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="plus">50plus</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="bbb">bbb </li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="bvnl">bvnl</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="cda">cda</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="pvv">PVV</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="christenunie">christenunie</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="d66">D66</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="denk">Denk</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="fvd">FVD</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="ja21">JA21</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="nsc">NSC</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="pvda">PVDAGROENLINKS</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="pvdd">PVDD</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="sgp">SGP</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="sp">SP</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="volt">Volt</li>
    <li onclick="incrementClicks(this)" class="grid-item" id="vvd">VVD</li>
</ul>
```

now i don't know how to make a JavaScript to sort the list based on the amount of clicks. so on popularity? is there any one who can help
i don't really have experience with JavaScript.

i tried somethings but they didn't work.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried and describe more exactly what you want it to do and how it has failed to do it. We aren't an ab initio coding service, but we are very happy to help debug your own code.

Comment: What does the CSS have to do with this?

Comment: Add a `data-clicks` attribute to the LI. When the user clicks on it, increment the value there. Then sort all the LIs using this as the key.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by *@Barmer;* you can implement your requirement using ***[`data-clicks`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*)*** attribute. I have removed some of the lines from your code. Something like:

```js
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item');
const list = document.getElementById('Partijensort');

list.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('grid-item')) {
        let clicks = event.target.getAttribute('data-clicks') ?? 0;
        event.target.setAttribute('data-clicks', ++clicks);
        sortListItems();
    }
});

function sortListItems() {
  const listItemsArr = Array.from(listItems);
  listItemsArr.sort(function(a, b) {
    const clicksA = a.getAttribute('data-clicks') ?? 0;
    const clicksB = b.getAttribute('data-clicks') ?? 0;
    return clicksB - clicksA;
  });
  listItemsArr.forEach(function(listItem) {
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  });
}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10vw;
  width: 10vw;
  margin-top: 1vw;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25));
}
```

```html
<ul id="Partijensort" class="grid-container">
  <li data-clicks="0" class="grid-item" id="plus">50plus</li>
  <li data-clicks="0" class="grid-item" id="bbb">bbb </li>
  <li data-clicks="0" class="grid-item" id="bvnl">bvnl</li>
  <li data-clicks="0" class="grid-item" id="cda">cda</li>
  <li data-clicks="0" class="grid-item" id="pvv">PVV</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please remove the `list.innerHTML = '';` There's no need to do that!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can sort a list with CSS  :

```js
function orderChild(event) {
  let li = event.target.closest('.order-me')
  if (li) li.style.order -= 1;
}
document.querySelector('.grid-container').onclick = orderChild
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.grid-item {
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item::after{
  content: 'style="' attr(style) '"';
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grid-container" onclick="orderChild">
    <li class="grid-item order-me">50plus</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">bbb </li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">bvnl</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">cda</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">PVV</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">christenunie</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">D66</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">Denk</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">FVD</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">JA21</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">NSC</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">PVDAGROENLINKS</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">PVDD</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">SGP</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">SP</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">Volt</li>
    <li class="grid-item order-me">VVD</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Cool beans, you should use event delegation so you only need a single handler.

Comment: @RuanMendes I'm not good in inlined onevents, anyone welcome to inline it properly